# Moodle database upgrade

Tags: moodle

I want to upgrade moodle databse from 1.9.5 to moodle 2.7.2.

I have one site in moodle 1.9.5 and another in moodle 2.7.2.

I want my whole database of moodle 1.9.5 in moodle 2.7.2.

I read various docs but all in vain.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps to upgrade from 1.9x to 2.7.2 is an easy process. But before you start the process , please make sure you first do the following

1. Read the release notes for moodle 2.2 and the latest plugins in it.
2. Backup the full Database.
3. Backup full moodledata.
4. Check the backups carefully.
5. Purge all PHP caches

Also check for updated versions of the plugins in moodle 1.9x and download the updated versions before upgrading. Uninstall the plugins not supported by the updated version.

Download the latest version of moodle 2.2 from - https://download.moodle.org/releases/legacy/

You should put your site into Maintenance Mode to stop any non-admin users from logging in.

Once done,

1. Replace the old code with the newer version code
2. Login to your moodle site , you will get a page to upgrade moodle database or else go to     *Settings > Site Adminstration > Notifications* which will trigger moodle to self-update.

Now once the process is completed , you have moodle version 2.2 installed. 
Download the latest moodle 2.7.2 from - https://download.moodle.org/releases/latest/

Now change the moodle 2.2 code with new moodle 2.7.2 code and continue the process as above. Once the process is over , you will have the moodle upgraded from 1.9x to 2.7.2

**Now the Database you have for moodle 2.7.2 is what you need.**

Backup the database and use it for moodle2.7.2 . If in case you want to use this in your moodle 2.7.2 site after renaming it , just replace the name of your database with this renamed database name in config.php file.

Please make sure you import the database back for your moodle 1.9x site and replace the old moodle 1.9x code with new one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in stages - it doesn't always go smoothly so expect some errors along the way. Backup the database and the moodledata folder at each stage.

First download and upgrade to the latest version of 1.9.x - https://download.moodle.org/releases/legacy/

Then upgrade to the latest version of 2.2 from 1.9 https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Upgrading_to_Moodle_2.2

Then you can upgrade to 2.7 from 2.2 - https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Upgrading

You will also need to upgrade any plugins you have installed at each stage too. ie download the 2.2 version of a 1.9 plugin - this is so the plugin can upgrade the database.

Good luck!